# Generating blank PDF file from response in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, pdf, axios

I'm getting below response of axios call:

[Click here to download response (PDF)](https://gist.github.com/apoorva-shah/ff9bcf93ccb8f3547a6e1bab57a1769a/raw/814121a3600fcba2be494746cae217d44cbae353/test-pdf-response.txt)

When I'm trying to generate PDF from above link response PDF generated with blank pages

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFileSync("12345678.pdf", response.data, 'binary');
```

**axios call:**

```
const url = 'url-here'

const headers = {
    'headers-here'
  };
const axiosConfig = {
    headers,
  };

axios.get(url, axiosConfig)
    .then((response) => {

     var fs = require('fs');
     fs.writeFileSync("12345678.pdf", response.data, 'binary'); 

     callback(null, response.data);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        logger.error(error.stack || error.message || error);
        callback(error, null);
});
```

Can anyone please help me to generate correct PDF?

Comment: It looks like you should be streaming the `axios` response into a `Buffer` or writable stream. Alternatively, pipe your response into `fs` - https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosconfig

Comment: @ethane What should I do?  Can you please suggest ?

Comment: Could you please add your `axios` request code to your question.

Comment: Sure, give me some time.

Comment: @ethane I've updated my question with axios request code.

Comment: Can you instead try `response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('12345678.pdf'))`. I suspect the way you are currently doing it only writes the first chunk into the stream. Another example of streaming with `axios`: https://github.com/andrewstart/axios-streaming/blob/master/request.js

Comment: Okay, let me try

Comment: @ethane I've tried it but not working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190263/discussion-between-ethane-and-milan).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The correct `responseType` value in the `axios` request config needs to be set to `stream` as well as `pipe`ing the response into a writable stream.

```
axios({ 
  method:'get', 
  url: 'someUrl', 
  responseType: 'stream' // #1 
}) 
.then(function (response) { 
  response.data.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('12345678.pdf')) // #2
});
```

Comment: This saved me a lot time. In my case I was getting the stream then sending it to another api for it to be uploaded. I didn't specify the responseType in the request, changed it to `stream` and it worked.

Comment: I have wasted 4 hours! Thanks

Comment: Thanks for this, I had already 12 hours wasted!